# form not working in php e-commerce wbsite

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to create an e commerce website for my semester project, but i cant seem to understand the problem with this code.I'm trying to take input from the admin regarding product name,image,details etc and then sending it to php code for processing and submitting it to the database,but the form isn't submitting anything.Here's the code:
`<form action="inventory_list.php" method="post" name="f1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Product Name:<input type="text" id="product_name" size="60" ><br>
      Cost:<input type="text" size="10" id="product_cost" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"><br>
                        Category:<select id="category" >
                        <option value="Watches">Watches</option>
                        <option values="Footwear">Footwear</option>
                        <option value="Apparels">Apparels</option>
                        </select><br>
                        Sub-Category:<select id="sub_category" >
                        <option value="Men">Men</option>
                        <option values="Women">Women</option>
                        </select><br>
                        Product Details:<textarea id="product_details"name="textarea" cols="60" rows="5" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>
                        Stock:<input type="text" size="10" id="stock" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"><br>
                        Product Image:<input type="file" id="image"><br>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add Item"><br>
                    </form>`

and this my php code:

```
     if(isset($_POST['product_name'])){
      $product_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
      $product_cost=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_cost']);
      $category=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
      $sub_category=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sub_category']);
      $product_details=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_details']);
      $stock=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stock']);

  //Check if product already exists in the database
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name'");
  $row_count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
  if($row_count>0){
      echo 'Product already exists in the database,<a href="inventory_list.php">Back</a>';

  }else{

    //Add this product to database
    $sql2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (product_name, price, details, category, subcategory, stock, date_added) VALUES('$product_name','$product_cost', '$product_details', '$category', '$sub_category', '$stock', now())")or die(mysql_error());
    $pid=mysql_insert_id($sql);

    //UPload image to new folder
    $newname="$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"E:\Applications\Xampp\htdocs\The Store\Main\inventory_images/{$newname}");
    header("location:inventory_list.php");
    exit();
  }
```

}

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Obligatory Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I actually came to know about mysqli later.I'm new to programming, and my submissions are close,so changing the mysql statements everywhere is kind of difficult for me.

Comment: Personally if I were a tutor I would fail anyone who uses mysql_*. But im a meanie... good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your HTML form, each input needs a name as well as an id:

```
Product Name:<input type="text" id="product_name" size="60" ><br>
```

Should be:

```
Product Name:<input type="text" id="product_name" name="product_name" size="60" ><br/>
```

Every one of your inputs needs a name. The $_POST array derives from the input names, so they all need to match your PHP code as well. Also note @Loz Cherone's comment. Mysql functions are deprecated, and open you up to a variety of nasty attacks.

Comment: It's working..!!!Thank You so much..!!I've been trying this for days.I can atleast think about submitting my project on time now.

Answer (score -1):

So Ive been going trough your project since there is nothing to do today at work and I noticed a couples of things.

First of all, like lars said, a POST use the name of the form to get his data, not the ID.
You also had some typos in your SELECT list where ''value'' where written ''values''.

So I change your code a little bit and you only have to make sure that you can connect to your DB and your set !

```
<form action="inventory_list.php" method="post" name="f1" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Product Name:<input type="text" name="product_name"  size="60" ><br>

Cost:<input type="text" size="10" name="product_cost" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"><br>

Category:<select name="category"> 
    <option value="Watches">Watches</option>
    <option value="Footwear">Footwear</option>
    <option value="Apparels">Apparels</option>
</select><br>

Sub-Category:<select name="sub_category"> 
    <option value="Men">Men</option>
    <option value="Women">Women</option>
</select><br>

Product Details:<textarea name="product_details" cols="60" rows="5" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>

Stock:<input type="text" size="10" name="stock" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"><br>

Product Image:<input type="file" name="image"><br>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add Item"><br>
```

and your inventory_list.php

```
  if(isset($_POST['product_name'])){
  $product_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
  $product_cost=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_cost']);
  $category=$_POST['category'];
  $sub_category=$_POST['sub_category'];
  $product_details=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_details']);
  $stock=$_POST['stock'];

 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name'");
 $row_count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
  if($row_count>0){
      echo 'Product already exists in the database,<a href="inventory_list.php">Back</a>';

  }else{

    //Add this product to database
    $sql2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (product_name, price, details, category, subcategory, stock, date_added) VALUES('$product_name','$product_cost', '$product_details', '$category', '$sub_category', '$stock', now())")or die(mysql_error());
    $pid=mysql_insert_id($sql);

    //UPload image to new folder
    $newname="$pid.jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"E:\Applications\Xampp\htdocs\The Store\Main\inventory_images/{$newname}");
    header("location:inventory_list.php");
    exit();
   }
```

}

Hope it helps !

Comment: Ohhh..!!Didn't notice it.Thank you for your help.